# Immediately forward to other page after a date is clicked in DateField in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, onclick, wicket, datefield

as in topic - I want to forward to other page after a date is clicked in DateField in Apache Wicket (something like setResponsePage works with buttons).

is there any way to achieve that? Here's my DateField:

```
    final DateField datePublishDateFrom = new DateField("publishDateFromInput", new Model<Date>(Const.DATE)) {

        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
            return DateTextField.forDatePattern(id, dateFieldModel, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    };

    add(datePublishDateFrom);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution, similar to what @svenmeier suggested. Adding behaviour works just fine

```
  final DateField datePublishDateFrom = new DateField("publishDateFromInput", new Model<Date>(Const.DATE)) {

        @Override
    protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
                 DateTextField dateInput =  DateTextField.forDatePattern(id, dateFieldModel, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                dateInput.add(createAjax());
            return dateInput;
        }
    };  



private AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior createAjax() {
    return new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            setResponsePage(BasePage.class);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read DateTimeField's javadoc: it contains some tips on how to ajaxify the component with AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.

In #onUpdate() you can then just use #setResponsePage().